# how can I select data in a multiindex dataFrame and have the result dataFrame have an appropriate index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a multiindex DataFrame and I'm trying to select data in it base on certain criteria, so far so good.  The problem is that once I have selected my data using .loc and pd.IndexSlice, the resulting DataFrame which should logically have less rows and less element in the first level of the multiindex keeps exactly the same multiIndex but with some keys in it refering to empty dataframe.

I've tried creating a completely new DataFrame with a new index, but the structure of my data set is complicating and there is not always the same number of elements in a given level, so it is not easy to created a dataFrame with the right shape in which I can put the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(3) #so my exemple is reproductible

idx = pd.IndexSlice

iterables = [['A','B','C'],[0,1,2],['some','rdm','data']]

my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables,names = 
                                                ['first','second','third'])

my_columns = ['col1','col2','col3']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(10,size = 
                                       (len(my_index),len(my_columns))),
                   index = my_index,
                   columns = my_columns
                    )

#Ok, so let's say I want to keep only the elements in the first level of my index (["A","B","C"]) for
#which the total sum in column 3 is less than 35 for some reasons

boolean_mask = (df1.groupby(level = "first").col3.sum() < 35).tolist()
first_level_to_keep = df1.index.levels[0][boolean_mask].tolist()

#lets select the wanted data and put it in df2
df2 = df1.loc[idx[first_level_to_keep,:,:],:]
```

So far, everything is as expected

The problem is when I want to access the df2 index. I expected the following:

```py
df2.index.levels[0].tolist() == ['B','C']
```

to be true.  But this is what gives a True statement:

```py
df2.index.levels[0].tolist() == ['A','B','C']
```

So my question is the following: is there a way to select data and to have in retrun a dataFrame with a multiindex reflecting what is in it.  Because I find weird to be able to select non existing data in my df2:

I tried to put some images of the dataframes in question but I couldn't because I dont't have enough «reputation»... sorry about that.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you delete the rows corresponding to a particular value in an index level, that value still exists. You can reset the index and then set those columns back as an index in order to generate a MultiIndex with new level values.

```
df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index(['first','second','third'])

print(df2.index.levels[0].tolist() == ['B','C'])

True
```